# C++ server (using WSAPoll/poll) receiving 2 client connection requests for a single HTTP request from browser?

Tags: c++, winsock

I am experimenting with sockets on Windows (C++ program). I am sending an HTTP request (plain text) from a browser as an exercise and the server sends a response. I use `WSAPoll()` to deal with multiple client connection requests and events.

The program seems to work OK, but when even though I only have 1 client and send 1 request, the server indicates that it receives 2 requests for a client to connect. I get a request after the `fetch` command from the webpage is triggered (fd = 196), and I seem to have 1 right after I have sent the response (fd = 200) -- of course, fd number will change depending on the machine it is running on. These are just the numbers I get when I run the program for illustration purposes. The IP address (client/browser) is the same but is a new fd value.

### Edit 1:

PS1: I am running the HTML page locally (opening the file in the browser - it's not loaded up from the server, which is why I would expect a single connection). PS2: I have looked into Chrome's Network activity console and only see 1 request made to the server (fetch). I read about pre-flight request but don't see an OPTION request being made in addition to GET in this example).

### Edit 2:

I thought I would also clarify the fact that I ended up managing to trigger a pre-flight request from the browser side (with the webpage running on localhost) and successfully respond to the OPTIONS request on the server side with the following:

```
response += "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n"; //localhost:29015
response += "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true\r\n";
response += "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS\r\n";
response += "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization\r\n";
response += "Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400\r\n\r\n";
```

This is just to say that the 2 requests for a client connection I get, are not related to the pre-flight method. I do indeed get an OPTION followed by a GET request and these requests came from the same client (fd = 196). I still have no idea why I then get to 2 client connection requests when I click on that button. I think that's something I am going to have to live with). Edge and Chrome do the same thing so it seems to be standard way for browsers to do things. If an insider knows, still interested in the answer.

### End of edit.

Here is what I get in the console:

```
$ ./Server
Size of fds before WSAPoll 1
Size of fds before WSAPoll 1
Size of fds before WSAPoll 1

        Client IP addr: 127.0.0.1
        Size of fds after insert client 2 196

Size of fds before WSAPoll 2
some activity from client 196

Received data from client 196: GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:27015
Connection: keep-alive
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="113", "Chromium";v="113", "Not-A.Brand";v="24"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Accept: */*
Origin: null
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9


Size of fds before WSAPoll 2

        Client IP addr: 127.0.0.1
        Size of fds after insert client 3 200

Size of fds before WSAPoll 3
Size of fds before WSAPoll 3
Size of fds before WSAPoll 3
```

Why do I get multiple client connection requests using different fd numbers (same IP address, though), even though I seem to only make one single request from the browser?

Here is the code I am using for both the server and the HTML page:

```cpp
// Compile with clang++ -o Server Server1.cpp -lWS2_32
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>

#include <vector>
#include <string>

#pragma include(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsadata;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsadata);
    SOCKET listen_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    assert(listen_socket != INVALID_SOCKET);

#if _WIN32
    unsigned long non_blocking = 1;
    ioctlsocket(listen_socket, FIONBIO, &non_blocking);
#else
#endif

    sockaddr_in server_addr{};
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(27015);

    bind(listen_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));

    listen(listen_socket, 4);

    WSAPOLLFD listen_fd {
        .fd = listen_socket,
        .events = POLLRDNORM,
    };

    std::vector<WSAPOLLFD> fds;
    fds.push_back(listen_fd);

    uint32_t count = 0;

    for (;;) {
#if _WIN32
        fprintf(stderr, "Size of fds before WSAPoll %llu\n", fds.size());
        int result = WSAPoll(fds.data(), fds.size(), 1000); // no timeout, wait indefinitely       
        if (fds[0].revents & POLLRDNORM) {
            // accept new cient connection
            sockaddr_in client_addr{};
            int client_addr_size = sizeof(client_addr);
            SOCKET client_socket = accept(listen_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &client_addr_size);
            assert(client_socket != INVALID_SOCKET);

            char client_ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(client_addr.sin_addr), client_ip, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
            fprintf(stderr, "\n\tClient IP addr: %s\n", client_ip);

            WSAPOLLFD client_fd {
                .fd = client_socket,
                .events = POLLRDNORM,
            };

            fds.push_back(client_fd);
            fprintf(stderr, "\tSize of fds after insert client %llu %llu\n\n", fds.size(), client_fd.fd);
        }

        //for (uint32_t i = 1; i < fds.size(); ++i) {
        for (auto iter = fds.begin() + 1; iter != fds.end();) {
            //for (size_t i = 1; i < fds.size(); ++i) {
            if (iter->revents & (POLLRDNORM | POLLERR | POLLHUP)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "some activity from client %lld\n\n", iter->fd);
                char buffer[1024];
                memset(buffer, 0x0, sizeof(buffer));
                int bytes_read = recv(iter->fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, 0);
                if (bytes_read > 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Received data from client %lld: %s\n\n", iter->fd, buffer);
                    std::string msg = "Count = " + std::to_string(count++);
                    std::string response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
                    response += "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n";
                    response += "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n";
                    response += "Content-Length: " + std::to_string(msg.size()) + "\r\n\r\n";
                    response += msg;
                    send(iter->fd, response.c_str(), response.size(), 0);
                }
                else if (bytes_read == 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Client disconnected %lld\n", iter->fd);
                    closesocket(iter->fd);
                    iter = fds.erase(iter);
                    fprintf(stderr, "Number of clients left: %llu\n", fds.size());
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    assert(0);
                }
            }
            iter++;
        }
#else
        int result = poll(&listen_fd, 1, -1); // indefinite timeout
#endif
    }

    closesocket(listen_socket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ARTS Testing Server</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to My Webpage</h1>
        <button onclick="sendRequest()">Send Request</button>
        <div id="response"></div>
        <script>
            function sendRequest() {
                console.log("in send request\n");
                fetch('http://localhost:27015/')
                    .then(function(response) {
                        if (response.ok) {
                            console.log("OK\n");
                            return response.text();
                        } else {
                            throw new Error("Request failed with status: " + response.status);
                        }
                    })
                    .then (function(responseText) {
                        console.log("HERE");
                        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = responseText;
                    })
                    .catch (function(error) {
                    
                    });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I recommend a network debugger like Wireshark to see what's really transmitted. Are you 100% sure that the client only sends one single request, and using only one single connection?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no I am not. And I am a newbie when it comes to this topic. I will have a look at Wireshark, thx for the tip. I am using Chrome maybe Chrome can record and report the number of requests?

Comment: Yes all browsers have tools to show network requests and responses.

Comment: Do be aware that [`WSAPoll()` is buggy](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2012/10/10/wsapoll-is-broken/).

Comment: @RemyLebeau ... aie. Is there an alternative? Beside " In the mean time we’ve just reverted to the old select()-using code instead, since select() does in fact mimic the “real” select much better…"

Comment: heads up. your recv code is assuming it will receive the entire request in one go. This is not guaranteed. It will almost certainly work with small messages from connections on the same machine. But real payloads from real networked machines dont work like that, you must loop till you receive the whole message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP is stateless. Even with keep-alives, browsers are not required to reuse connections at all, or the connections may have timed out and been closed between requests.

So, if the browser retrieves your HTML page as a remote file, it is using one connection (not so when loading the HTML as a local file), and there is no guarantee that the `fetch` command will reuse that same connection, even if it is to the same host/port that the HTML page came from.  Even multiple `fetch`es might use different connections.  Most browsers will maintain several connections to a server at a time to help it facilitate the loading of multiple resources in parallel (in case an HTML page has references to other files, such as images, scripts, etc).

You can use your browser's built-in debugging tools to see whether or not this is actually the case in your situation.

As for your actual code, I see a few problems with it:

- lack of adequate error handling.
- you are completely ignoring `WSAPoll()`'s return value before evaluating the states of the `WSAPOLLFD` structs.  The return value tells you whether the `revents` members were actually updated or not.
- `accept()` always returns a blocking socket, even if the listening socket is non-blocking.  If you want the client to be non-blocking, you need to set it explicitly.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#if _WIN32

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#pragma include(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

typedef SOCKET socket_t;
typedef WSAPOLLFD pollfd_t;
typedef int socklen_t;

static const SOCKET c_INVALID_SOCKET = INVALID_SOCKET;
static const int c_SOCKET_ERROR = SOCKET_ERROR;
static const int c_EWOULDBLOCK = WSAEWOULDBLOCK;
static const int c_EAGAIN = WSAEWOULDBLOCK;

#define LastErrNo WSAGetLastError()
#define Poll(fds, nfds, timeout) WSAPoll(fds, nfds, timeout)
#define CloseSocket(fd) closesocket(fd)

bool InitSocketLib() {
    WSADATA wsadata;
    int errCode = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsadata);
    return (errCode == 0);
}

void CleanupSocketLib() {
    WSACleanup();
}

bool MakeNonBlocking(SOCKET sckt) {
    unsigned long non_blocking = 1;
    return (ioctlsocket(sckt, FIONBIO, &non_blocking) == 0);
}

#else

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <unistd.h>
 
typedef int socket_t;
typedef pollfd pollfd_t;

static const int c_INVALID_SOCKET = -1;
static const int c_SOCKET_ERROR = -1;
static const int c_EWOULDBLOCK = EWOULDBLOCK;
static const int c_EAGAIN = EAGAIN;

#define LastErrNo errno
#define Poll(fds, nfds, timeout) poll(fds, nfds, timeout)
#define CloseSocket(fd) close(fd)

bool InitSocketLib() { return true; }
void CleanupSocketLib() { }

bool MakeNonBlocking(int fd) {
    int non_blocking = 1;
    return (ioctl(fd, FIONBIO, &non_blocking) == 0);

    /* alternatively:
    int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
    return (fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK) == 0);
    */
}

#endif

int main()
{
    if (!InitSocketLib()) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to initialize socket library, error: " << LastErrNo << '\n';
        return -1;
    }

    socket_t listen_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (listen_socket == c_INVALID_SOCKET) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to create listening socket, error: " << LastErrNo << '\n';
        return -1;
    }

    if (!MakeNonBlocking(listen_socket)) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to set listening socket to non-blocking, error: " << LastErrNo << '\n';
        return -1;
    }

    sockaddr_in server_addr{};
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(27015);

    if (bind(listen_socket, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&server_addr), sizeof(server_addr)) < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to bind listening socket, error: " << LastErrNo << '\n';
        return -1;
    }

    if (listen(listen_socket, 4) < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to open listening socket, error: " << LastErrNo << '\n';
        return -1;
    }

    pollfd_t listen_fd {
        .fd = listen_socket,
        .events = POLLRDNORM,
        .revents = 0
    };

    std::vector<pollfd_t> fds;
    fds.push_back(listen_fd);

    uint32_t count = 0;

    while (true) {
        std::cerr << "Size of fds before poll " << fds.size() << '\n';

        int result = Poll(fds.data(), fds.size(), -1); // no timeout, wait indefinitely
        if (result < 0) {
            std::cerr << "Unable to poll, error: " << LastErrNo << '\n';
            return -1;
        }

        if (result == 0) // timeout
            continue;

        for (auto iter = fds.begin(); iter != fds.end(); ) {
            if (iter->revents & POLLRDNORM) {
                if (iter->fd == listen_socket) {
                    // accept new client connection

                    sockaddr_in client_addr{};
                    socklen_t client_addr_size = sizeof(client_addr);

                    socket_t client_socket = accept(listen_socket, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&client_addr), &client_addr_size);
                    if (client_socket == c_INVALID_SOCKET) {
                        std::cerr << "Unable to accept a client, error: " << LastErrNo << '\n';
                    }
                    else if (!MakeNonBlocking(client_socket)) {
                        std::cerr << "Unable to set client socket to non-blocking, error: " << LastErrNo << '\n';
                        CloseSocket(client_socket);
                    }
                    else {
                        char client_ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN] = {};
                        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(client_addr.sin_addr), client_ip, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
                        std::cerr << "\n\tClient IP addr: " << client_ip << ", port: " << ntohs(client_addr.sin_port) << '\n';

                        pollfd_t client_fd {
                            .fd = client_socket,
                            .events = POLLRDNORM,
                            .revents = 0
                        };

                        //auto offset = std::distance(fds.begin(), iter);
                        fds.push_back(client_fd);
                        iter = fds.begin() /* + offset */;
                    
                        std::cerr << "\tSize of fds after insert: " << fds.size() << ", client: " << client_socket << "\n\n";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // read from client connection

                    std::cerr << "Some activity from client: " << iter->fd << "\n\n";
                    char buffer[1024];

                    int bytes_read = recv(iter->fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
                    if (bytes_read > 0) {
                        std::cerr << "Received data from client: " << iter->fd << ": ";
                        std::cerr.write(buffer, bytes_read);
                        std::cerr << "\n\n";

                        // TODO: parse the request, don't send a reply until the end of the request is actually received...
                        std::string msg = "Count = " + std::to_string(count++);
                        std::string response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
                        response += "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n";
                        response += "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n";
                        response += "Content-Length: " + std::to_string(msg.size()) + "\r\n\r\n";
                        response += msg;

                        // TODO: if send() fails with EWOULDBLOCK/EGAIN,
                        // cache the unsent data and wait for poll() to
                        // tell you when it is OK to keep sending it ...
                        send(iter->fd, response.c_str(), response.size(), 0);
                    }
                    else if (bytes_read == 0) {
                        iter->revents |= POLLHUP;
                    }
                    else if ((LastErrNo != c_EWOULDBLOCK) && (LastErrNo != c_EAGAIN)) {
                        iter->revents |= POLLERR;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (iter->revents & (POLLERR | POLLHUP)) {
                if (iter->fd != listen_socket) {
                    if (iter->revents & POLLHUP) {
                        std::cerr << "Client disconnected: " << iter->fd << '\n';
                    } else {
                        std::cerr << "Unable to read from client: " << iter->fd << ", error: " << LastErrNo << '\n';
                    }
                    socket_t client_socket = iter->fd;
                    CloseSocket(client_socket);
                    iter = fds.erase(iter);
                    std::cerr << "\tSize of fds after remove: " << fds.size() << ", client: " << client_socket << "\n\n";
                    continue;
                }
            }

            ++iter;
        }
    }

    CloseSocket(listen_socket);

    CleanupSocketLib();

    return 0;
}
```

---

That being said, note that [WSAPoll is broken](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2012/10/10/wsapoll-is-broken/) to begin with.  Consider an alternative design on Windows.  You could just use `select()` instead, which on Windows does not have the same limitations that it does on other platforms.  Or, you can switch over to using Overlapped I/O or I/O Completion Ports instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer. I will check the return codes yes, but I thought for quick testing I could go with ignoring them at the beginning. I believe pushing to std::vector happens outside of the for loop where I iterate over WSAPOLLFDs but I will double-check. Thanks again for this great answer and the code sample. Much appreciated and very valuable. Though side question: in my case the page is run locally and the HTTP request only happens when you click on the button. So the browser should only call the server with fetch?

Comment: "*I believe pushing to std::vector happens outside of the for loop*" - only for the listening socket. But every time the loop then detects a new client, you push into the vector, and if the vector reallocates its inner array then your loop iterator gets invalidated. You were correctly updating the iterator when `erase`'ing disconnected clients, but not when `push_back`'ing new clients. "*So the browser should only call the server with fetch?*" - in this case, yes

Comment: Still trying to understand the `vector` issue.  First loop
is just an infinite loop. I might as well have used while(). Second inner
loop is where I iterate over the clients and only then does the code
potentially erase an element from the list. So adding an element and removing one seems
to me independent from each other?
`std::vector list;
list.push_back(listening_fd);
for (;;) {
  if (new_client) {
    list.push_back(client_fd);
  }
  for (auto iter = list.begin()+1; iter != list.end(); ( {
    if (closing_socket)
   iter = list.erase(iter);
    else
   iter++;
  }
}`

Comment: @user18490 nevermind that part about invalidating the iterator. I misread the code.

Comment: No worries. I am not so confident with my c++ coding skills so I was interested in learning. Thanks for your help. I am still trying to figure out where is this second connection coming from.